# SUMMARY - per hour, in interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I have following data:

[image]

Which means, that I need **10 people** between **2h** and **8h** for working on **Task 1** etc.

How to create timeline with summary of workers needed per hour on all the running tasks? Like this:

[image]

Comment: What does your current query look like?    What error are you getting?

Comment: It is always better if you provided input data as text instead of images

Comment: @kannan: oh, you're right, so next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple conditional aggregation in concert with a CROSS APPLY should do the trick

```
Declare @YourTable table ([Task] int,[Start] datetime,[End] datetime,[People] int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'2017-03-17 02:00:00','2017-03-17 08:00:00',10)
,(2,'2017-03-17 02:00:00','2017-03-17 08:00:00',5)
,(3,'2017-03-17 03:00:00','2017-03-17 05:00:00',8)
,(4,'2017-03-17 04:00:00','2017-03-17 06:00:00',10)

Select [01:00] = sum(case when DatePart(HOUR,D)=1 then People else 0 end)
      ,[02:00] = sum(case when DatePart(HOUR,D)=2 then People else 0 end)
      ,[03:00] = sum(case when DatePart(HOUR,D)=3 then People else 0 end)
      ,[04:00] = sum(case when DatePart(HOUR,D)=4 then People else 0 end)
      ,[05:00] = sum(case when DatePart(HOUR,D)=5 then People else 0 end)
      ,[06:00] = sum(case when DatePart(HOUR,D)=6 then People else 0 end)
      ,[07:00] = sum(case when DatePart(HOUR,D)=7 then People else 0 end)
      ,[08:00] = sum(case when DatePart(HOUR,D)=8 then People else 0 end)
      ,[09:00] = sum(case when DatePart(HOUR,D)=9 then People else 0 end)
 From  @YourTable
 Cross Apply (Select Top (DateDiff(HOUR,[Start],[End])+1) D=DateAdd(HOUR,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),[Start]) 
                 From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2 
              ) B
```

**Returns**

```
01:00   02:00   03:00   04:00   05:00   06:00   07:00   08:00   09:00
0       15      23      33      33      25      15      15      0
```

Comment: @gaffcz the cross apply just expands 1 record into many .  To better visualize what is happening, change it to SELECT * From YourTable ...

Comment: @gaffcz Cross Apply can be very helpful and the performance is respectable.   Within the CROSS APPLY we are just using an ad-hoc tally table to gnerate the span.  This can be done via a join as well.

Comment: @gaffcz Happy it helped

Answer (score 2):

You can use hours, tally table and pivot for getting this as below:

```
select ISNULL([1],0) as [1:00:00], [2] as [2:00:00],[3] as [3:00:00], [4] as [4:00:00],[5] as [5:00:00]
,[6] as [6:00:00],[7] as [7:00:00],[8] as [8:00:00],ISNULL([9],0) as [9:00:00]
from (
    select Hrs= Datepart(hour,RowN),SmPeople= sum(people) from Yourtask
    cross apply (
        select top (datediff(hour, [start],[end])+1) RowN= DateAdd(hour, row_number() over (order by (Select null))-1, [Start]) 
            from master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2
    ) a
    group by Datepart(hour,RowN)
) CalcuatedPeople
pivot (max(SmPeople) for hrs in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9])) p
```

Output as below:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 1:00:00 | 2:00:00 | 3:00:00 | 4:00:00 | 5:00:00 | 6:00:00 | 7:00:00 | 8:00:00 | 9:00:00 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|       0 |      15 |      23 |      33 |      33 |      25 |      15 |      15 |       0 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```